# Change ggplot2's default parameters/palette within a theme function

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

I am trying to redefine a plot's palette using a [personal theme function](https://github.com/laresbernardo/lares/blob/master/R/theme_lares2.R), but is seems I can't change a function within a function.

So, if I run the following I succeed in what I need, but not when I insert that line of code inside my theme.

```
my_colours_pal <- c("#EBB600", "#40A4D8", "#5D3A9B", "#DC3220", "#D35FB7, "#32CD32")
scale_colour_discrete <- function(...) ggplot2::scale_colour_manual(my_colours_pal)
```

Is there a way I could re-define "external" functions within my new function? It's like an `assign()` but with functions. Like:

```
changefxs <- function (condition) {
  my_colours_pal <- c("#EBB600", "#40A4D8", "#5D3A9B", "#DC3220", "#D35FB7, "#32CD32")
  scale_colour_discrete <- function(...) ggplot2::scale_colour_manual(my_colours_pal)
}
```

Comment: That's generally a bad idea, but technically you can use `<<-` rather than `<-` to set variables outside the scope of your function.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick Why would you say it's a bad idea? I tried that and got the error `cannot change value of locked binding for 'scale_colour_discrete'`

Comment: it's a bad idea because when side effects are not explicit the end user might not realise that variables from another environment are changed or which ones, or in which environment. To make it work here you could first define `scale_colour_discrete <- ggplot2::scale_colour_discrete` in your global environment first, then call `scale_colour_discrete <<- function(...) ggplot2::scale_colour_manual(my_colours_pal)` in your function as @MrFlick suggests, but there's probably a much cleaner way of doing what you want. (it's generally a bad idea to use `assign` as well btw :) )

Comment: Maybe be sure that you understand all you can do with `ggplot2::theme` before trying to use other functions.

Comment: Well, this did the trick: `assign("scale_colour_discrete", function(..., values = my_pal) ggplot2::scale_colour_discrete(..., values = values), envir=as.environment(1))`